# How to set caller id or remote pary id linphone?

Tags: ios, linphone, linphone-sdk, caller-id

I have one ios application with audio calling functionality using linphone. I have to change caller id or remote party id. i.e. I have registered with 1000 number. But while calling i have multiple DIDs to choose from in my application. Does linphone provide any option other than setting custom header for this?

From: "1000" sip:1000@172.0.0.0 
I have registered with 1000 but at time of calling i want to use 1001.
So in above invite header i want to replace 1000 with 1001.

Here i want to change from to other DID at time of calling. Does linphone provide any option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like as of now linphone for ios is not providing such options.

So, i have set parameter as custom header using below code.

```
 linphone_call_params_add_custom_header(lcallParams,"X-HeaderName",["1001" UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change CallerID by adding a SIP Header **Remote-Party-ID: "<NEW_CALLERID>"**. No Need to change the FROM Header. If you change the FROM Header it will break the SIP Authentication & Authorization Flow.

Comment: I'm new to Linphone, how do you set custom headers in Linphone? Googling just brings be back to this answer.